# Hiding Three20 Navigation Bar Back Item

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I am sort of newbie in Three20 world, and I am trying to hide the back/left button in navigation bar.

Below is the method I am calling to hide it:

```
[[TTNavigator navigator].topViewController.navigationController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];

[[TTNavigator navigator].topViewController.navigationController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

Apparently, both the methods doesn't hide the back button. What I am here trying to do is, push the viewcontroller, and when the new controller arrives it doesn't show the back button, yet I had another button there which pop's the view.

I have also tried different routes as:

```
[VC.navigationController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:Yes];
```

The funny part is I am about to set the Title though as:

```
[VC.navigationItem setTitle:@"Options"];
```

Any help here will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try here: [Crappy iOS APIs – UINavigationController](http://rafaelsteil.com/2011/07/23/crappy-ios-apis-uinavigationcontroller/)

Notice that Rafael does this in the new controller, **not** in the controller which does the push.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

It works for me.
Dave